# Hide button if array index value is under 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide a certain button if there is not more than 3 instructions saved in the array.  Valueindex is a variable that i count all the instructions. So if valueIndex holds less than 3 instructions i want to hide show-all and hide-all button. I am new to javascript and jquery and i would love any pointers i could get.

```
var valueIndex = 0;

$.each(data, function(index){
    valueIndex++
    if(index > 3 ) {
        st += "<tr class='hideItems'><td>"+data[index]+"</td>";
        $(' .show-all ').addClass('new-class');
    }
    else {
        st += "<tr><td>"+data[index]+"</td>";
    }      
}); 

$('.show-all').click(function (event) {
    $(".hideItems").show();
    $(".show-all").hide();
    $(".hide-all").show(); // Lägg till event på show close
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('.hide-all').click(function () {
    $(".hideItems").hide();
    $(".show-all").show();
    $(".hide-all").hide();
});

$("#showInstructions").html(st);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your loop, you can add:

```
$(".show-all,.hide-all").toggle(valueIndex >= 3);
```

The jquery toggle method provides a flag option whether to show/hide the element (https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

This is the equivalent of:

```
if (valueIndex>=3) {
    $(".show-all").show();
    $(".hide-all").show();
} else {
    $(".show-all").hide();
    $(".hide-all").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a css class like:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

and give your buttons this class. Then when your condition is reached, simply do

```
$('.button').removeClass('hide');
```